# Android, WebGL in WebView : 'Uncaught ReferenceError: mat4 is not defined'

Tags: java, android, webgl

I am trying to display this [WebGL demo](https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/tree/gh-pages/tutorial/sample5) in an Android WebView. It works perfectly well locally on my computer but not in my Android demo app. My Android demo app is just an activity with a WebView ; I run the following code:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

I put all the files of the demo WebGL project (html+js+css) in the assets folder of my project.

I get the following error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(230)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: mat4 is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/webgl-demo.js (230)
```

That is ti say that there is an error on this line of code :

```
const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem: just had to add in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change traget version 30 then it will work properly for you